# Custom Menu visible to one document in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, menu, toolbar

I have created customized menu and toolbar in MS Excel. I wanted to show this menu and toolbar to specific document only. When I open any other xls file, it shows that menu and toolbar.

```
MS Excel 2003
```

How to do that using vba-excel macro or any other way to do that?

If you need more information, please ask me.

Thanks :)

Comment: I never do this sort of thing, but there is a book titled "Professional Excel Development" that is full of info on exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - so this website will help you:
http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/custom-menus.htm

It actually works in Excel 2007 also, but adds the menu under the Add-Ins tab.

You basically need to access the code for `ThisWorkbook` in the VBA application.  From there, you can modify the `Application.CommandBars` object to do what you need.