# How to add icons to custom menu in excel - vba

Tags: vba, excel, menu, toolbar

I have created some custom menu referring ["Custom Menu visible to one document in Excel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446184/custom-menu-visible-to-one-document-in-excel). Now I want to add some icons to each menu item. Either that may be system icons or some others. Please provide some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `.FaceID` property. If you want to know what id to use, then download a FaceID Browser addin for excel. Example:

```
Set MenuItem = NewMenu.Controls.Add _
  (Type:=msoControlButton)
With MenuItem
    .Caption = "Save XML Data"
    .FaceId = 270
    .OnAction = "AskExportXml"
    .Enabled = True
End With
```

Comment: I have updated my question. This works fine. But, whenever opening the document it adds new menu item in that list. I mean that MenuItem is getting added to menu item, whenever I open the document. Please help to solve this.